# Can Hibernate ignore entity members when updating?

Tags: hibernate, spring

Is it possible to mark some members of an Entity as 'ignored' in an update query?

I basically, have an Entity, which can be updated. But not all members of the Entity can be updated once set. So when I use Spring to bind the form data to my Entity the fields which are not exposed on the form all have null values. When the Entity is updated the mapped columns have `null` values written in them.

I have put the unchangeable values has hidden form values for now, but I don't think this is the best solution. Is there a better one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution, IMO, is to avoid reconstructing a new instance of the entity from the form fields. Instead, take an existing, completely populated instance of the entity, change the values of the fields that are in the form, and then merge this entity.

The alternative is to mark the column as non updatable (with `@Column(updatable = false)`), but this will make the column non updatable for all the use-cases, whic I don't think it's a good idea, generally: if some fields may not be changed by some users, but may be changed by others, or by an administrative data migration tool, then setting the column as non-updatable will be annoying.